# Creating the same folder in all sub-directories of a folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am having difficulty getting the (simplified) batch-file below to work. It creates the a specific folder in all sub-directories of the specified directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "location=c:\test"
for /d %%d in (%location%\*) do (
  md "%%d\COMMONFOLDER"
)
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is your question?

Comment: Does the containing folder (e.g., `c:\test`) exist? Does it contain any folders? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal
set location=c:\test
FOR /D %%C in ("%location%\*") DO md %%C\COMMONFOLDER
```

works fine for me, any direct subfolders get a COMMONFOLDER made inside them.

eg.

- C:\test\SubLevel1\    gets a C:\test\SubLevel1\COMMONFOLDER
- C:\test\SubLevel1-1\  gets a C:\test\SubLevel1-1\COMMONFOLDER
- C:\test\SubLevel1\SubLev2 would not get a COMMONFOLDER

Not sure if this helps, but just add the @ECHO off and it works exactly as you said you wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "location=c:\test"
for /r "%location%" /d %%d in (*) do (
  md "%%d\COMMONFOLDER"
)
```